# Simplifying nested loops using recursion

Tags: python, numpy, recursion, nested-loops

Let's assume we have a three-dimensional array `x`. For each `k`, I want to have the mean of `x[:, :, k]` stored as `out[k]`. The task is simple if it is a 3D or 4D matrix, with the for loop like this:

```
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, [4, 4, 3])
out = np.zeros(x[0, 0, :].shape)
for k in range(3):
    out[k] =  np.mean(x[:, :, k])
    
x2 = np.random.normal(0, 1, [5, 5, 4, 6])
out2 = np.zeros(x2[0, 0, :, :].shape)
for k in range(4):
    for l in range(6):
        out2[k, l] = np.mean(x2[:, :, k, l])
```

But the code is getting ugly if I want to go for higher dimension (let's say I want to cover up to 100 dimension), since the number of nested loops increase.

I know that I have to do it recursively with 2D matrices serve as my base case, but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: You can't go over 32 dimensions.  Even if each dimension is size,2  2**32 is a big file.  And recusion in python isn't particularly efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need recursion for this case. Turns out my previous answer was pretty close, just need a few transposes.

```
x2 = np.random.normal(0, 1, [2, 2, 7, 5, 5, 4, 6])

dims = len(x2.shape)

out = np.mean(x2.T, axis = tuple(range(-2, -1))).T


print(out[0,0,0,0,0], np.mean(x2[:, :, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]))
```

Notably, the values between `out` and `np.mean` are sometimes slightly off on the last three digits, so there's some weird precision loss happening somehow.

If you must do it recursively...

```
x2 = np.random.normal(0, 1, [2, 2, 7, 5, 5, 4, 6])

def recursive_mean(x, out = None):
    if out is None:
        out = np.zeros(x.shape[2:])
        
    if len(x.shape) > 3:
        for i in range(x.shape[2]):
            out[i] = recursive_mean(x[:, :, i], out[i])
            
    else:
        for i in range(x.shape[2]):
            out[i] = np.mean(x[:, :, i])
        
        
    return out

out2 = recursive_mean(x2)

print(out2[0,0,0,0,0], np.mean(x2[:, :, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]))
print(out2[3, 1, 2, 0, 4], np.mean(x2[:, :, 3, 1, 2, 0, 4]))
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. But it doesn't provide generality to higher dimensions.

Comment: Ah, whoops, I got it casted backwards, you're right. Going to delete this answer and give it another shot.

Comment: @user129994 I've corrected the answer and did some test cases to verify it.

Comment: Thanks again. Your output has the size of 4x6. I expect to have a 5-dimensional matrix of size [7, 5, 5, 4, 6] for your x2 array.

Comment: Ah, basically the same idea, just change axis to (-2, -1). I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Everything looks right. However, is it possible to post the solution using recursive function?

Comment: @user129994 I've given it a shot. It passes my preliminary tests, but I'm always a little unsure when it comes to recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to take the mean along the first two axes. You can do this simply by `x.mean(axis=(0, 1))`

Example:

- `out*` is the mean calculated by your approach
- `out*_np` is the mean calculated by `np.mean` like I show above.

```
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, [4, 4, 3])
out = np.zeros(x[0, 0, :].shape)
out_np = x.mean(axis=(0,1))
for k in range(3):
    out[k] =  np.mean(x[:, :, k])

print(np.allclose(out, out_np)) # True

x2 = np.random.normal(0, 1, [5, 5, 4, 6])
out2 = np.zeros(x2[0, 0, :, :].shape)
out2_np = x2.mean(axis=(0,1))
for k in range(4):
    for l in range(6):
        out2[k, l] = np.mean(x2[:, :, k, l])

print(np.allclose(out2, out2_np)) # True
```

---

To generalize this to any function that operates on a 2D matrix, you can reshape your original matrix to a 3D matrix, apply your method over the last axis, and reshape the result to the required shape:

```
def apply_2dfunc(X, func):
    X_r = X.reshape((*X.shape[0:2], -1))
    res = np.zeros((X_r.shape[-1],))
    for i in range(len(res)):
        res[i] = func(X_r[:, :, i])

    return res.reshape(X.shape[2:])
```

With your example of `func=np.mean`,

```
out_g = apply_2dfunc(x, np.mean)
print(np.allclose(out_g, out)) # True


out2_g = apply_2dfunc(x2, np.mean)
print(np.allclose(out2_g, out2)) # True
```

Comment: I simplified the problem and post it as taking mean. But it is about mean value calculation. It is about converting nested loop to a recursive version

Comment: @user129994 can you give more details about what you really want to do? It is possible numpy already has a vectorized way to do this, instead of depending on python code and recursive functions

Comment: It is more about matrix manipulation that only works for 2D matrices.

Comment: @user129994 see my updated answer. I use the example of `np.mean`, but it can be any function that takes a 2d matrix and spits out a scalar. Of course, if your function takes the `axis` argument you can just use [`np.apply_over_axes`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.apply_over_axes.html)